# Calling class method through looping std::map

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, pointer-to-member

I got class called `CharacterAnimation` consists of one virtual method:

```
CharacterAnimation : public cocos2d::CCObject {
  public:
  ...
    virtual void start(float td);
}
```

and several inherited from it classes:

- `CharacterAnimationBlink`
- `CharactedAnimationDropTear`
- etc

What I want is:

1. Create

   ```
   std::map<std::string, CharacterAnimation*> animationsList;
   ```
2. Fill `animationList` like:

   ```
   animationsList["blink"] = new CharacterAnimationBlink(1,2,3);
   animationsList["dropTear"] = new CharacterAnimationDropTear(1,2);
   ```
3. Looping through this std::map
4. For each `std::map` element call

   ```
   this->schedule(schedule_selector(characterAnimationStartMethodPointer), Character::animationPeriod);
   ```

What should be placed instead of `currentAnimationStartMethodPointer`? How do I access a pointer to `start()` method of current object from `std::map`?

**From CCObject.h**

```
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_SCHEDULE)(float);
...
#define schedule_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_SCHEDULE)(&_SELECTOR)
```

Comment: how is `schedule_selector` defined ?

Comment: 2 Piotr S.: updated post by schedule_selector definition

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't control the declaration for the `schedule()` function, you can't get a single pointer to the `start()` function of a particular `CharacterAnimation` instance. Instead, you need two things here: a member function pointer, *and* a reference or pointer to the instance upon which that function should be called.

As presented in your question, it looks like `schedule()` demands a member function pointer (in particular, a function from the `CCObject` class). Your `CharacterAnimation` class inherits from `CCObject`, but a member function pointer to `CharacterAnimation::start()` is *not* a member function pointer to a `CCObject` function, assuming from the lack of a `virtual` or `override` specifier that `start()` is declared in `CharacterAnimation` and not inherited from `CCObject`.

Comment: But cocos2d-x uses the same logic as I am at scene code. **For example**: it is possible to define a class SomeScene (inherited from CCObject) with method like "someActionHere()" and pass it to schedule_selector() successfully. What is the difference? Thank you for replay anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd need to see more of this example code to speak with certainty. My answer is based on several assumptions extrapolated from what you shared here, but, as always, there's more to the real story.

Comment: I have created a new topic with more common question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279101/fetching-address-of-virtual-method-by-class-instance. Maybe it will be more detailed

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the global scheduler to call the `start` method every `Character::animationPeriod` seconds.

```
for (std::map<std::string, CharacterAnimation*>::iterator i = animationsList.begin();
     i != animationsList.end();
     ++i)
{
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(CharacterAnimation::start),
                                                                   i->second,
                                                                   Character::animationPeriod,
                                                                   false);
}
```